# Including distance in the least cost path analysis in QGIS

Tags: qgis, least-cost

I'd like to get the least cost path between two points. Currently I include slope as a cost layer.[image: The results are shown in the image below.]

However, I want QGIS to also consider distance. In this case, it could sacrifice the slope in order to reduce the distance of the path.

Is there any way to include this?

Comment: Isn't distance considered automatically, at least based on the accumulated cost? The longer the path, the more cells and thus the higher the accumulated costs. However, could it be that your layers are in a geographic CRS (like WGS84 `EPSG:4326`)? So distances would be in degrees - maybe this is the problem?

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I would try it!